# Ordenação decrescente em Lista Duplamente Encadeada Circular em C

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

To precisando de uma ajudinha aqui com Lista Circular Duplamente Encadeada para resolver um problema maior.

Preciso fazer uma função que já insira meus elementos em ordem decrescente. Meu código até funciona com entradas que só necessitam ser invertidas.`Ex: 1 2 3 4 5 6`, que sai `6 5 4 3 2 1`. O problema são com entradas do tipo `6 3 9 8` ... Onde acham que está o problema?

```
struct elemento{
  int altura;
  struct elemento *anterior;
  struct elemento *proximo;
 };
 typedef struct elemento Item;

typedef struct{
    int tamanhoLista;
    Item *primeiro;
    Item *ultimo;
}LCD_DE;

    void Inserir(LCD_DE *l){
    Item *novo = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));

    scanf("%d",&novo->altura);

    if(l->tamanhoLista == 0){
        l->primeiro = novo;
        l->ultimo = novo;
        novo->anterior = novo;
        novo->proximo =  novo;
    }
    else{
        if(novo->altura >= l->primeiro->altura){  //antes do primeiro
            l->primeiro->anterior = novo;
            l->ultimo->proximo = novo;
            novo->anterior = l->ultimo;
            novo->proximo = l->primeiro;
            l->primeiro = novo;
        }
        else if(novo->altura < l->ultimo->proximo->altura){ //depois do ultimo
            l->ultimo->proximo = novo;
            l->primeiro->anterior = novo;
            novo->anterior = l->ultimo;
            novo->proximo = l->primeiro;
            l->ultimo = novo;
        }
        else{
            Item *i,*j,*k,*aux;
            for(i=l->primeiro;i!=l->primeiro;i=i->proximo){
                for(j=l->primeiro->proximo;j!=l->primeiro;j=j->proximo){
                    k=j->proximo;
                    if(novo->altura >= j->altura){
                        i->proximo = novo;
                        novo->anterior = i;
                        j->anterior = novo;
                        novo->proximo = j;
                    }
                    else if(novo->altura < j->altura){
                            j->proximo = novo;
                            novo->anterior = j;
                            k->anterior = novo;
                            novo->anterior = k;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
     l->tamanhoLista++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho complicado ficar achando esse tipo de problema com ponteiros, preferi criar um novo exemplo.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Item
{
   int height;
   struct Item* prev;
   struct Item* next;
} Item;

typedef struct
{
   int size;
   Item* first;
   Item* last;
} List;

static void insert(List *list, int height)
{
   printf("* ===\n");

   Item *newItem = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));
   newItem->height = height;

   if (list->size == 0)
   {
      printf("* inserindo elemento %d em lista vazia\n", height);
      list->first = newItem;
      list->last = newItem;
      newItem->prev = newItem;
      newItem->next = newItem;
      list->size = 1;
      return;
   }

   if (height > list->first->height)
   {
      printf("* inserindo elemento %d antes do primeiro\n", height);
      list->first->prev = newItem;
      list->last->next = newItem;
      newItem->prev = list->last;
      newItem->next = list->first;
      list->first = newItem;
      list->size++;
      return;
   }

   if (height < list->last->height)
   {
      printf("* inserindo elemento %d depois do ultimo\n", height);
      list->last->next = newItem;
      list->first->prev = newItem;
      newItem->prev = list->last;
      newItem->next = list->first;
      list->last = newItem;
      list->size++;
      return;
   }

   printf("* inserindo elemento %d intermediario\n", height);
   Item* item = list->first;
   for (int i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
   {
      if (item->height < height)
         break;
      item = item->next;
   }

   item->prev->next = newItem;

   newItem->prev = item->prev;
   newItem->next = item;

   item->prev = newItem;

   list->size++;
}

static void print(List* list)
{
   printf("* ---\n");
   printf("* tamanho da lista: %d\n", list->size);
   Item* item = list->first;
   for (int i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
   {
      printf("* list[%d] = %d\n", i, item->height);
      item = item->next;
   }
}


int main(void)
{
   List list = { 0 };
   print(&list);

   insert(&list, 7);  // primeiro elemento
   print(&list);

   insert(&list, 2); // antes do primeiro elemento
   print(&list);

   insert(&list, 13); // depois do ultimo elemento
   print(&list);

   insert(&list, 9);  // elemento intermediario
   print(&list);
}
```

Veja em http://ideone.com/p0xSYt

Comment: Muuuuuito obrigada José, mesmo, a sacada do "item->prev->next = newItem" foi genial, nem pensei nesse nível de apontamento pra resolver o problema.Valeu mesmo :)